# Making @Html.DropDownList for searchable

Tags: javascript, asp.net, bootstrap-5

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjRH9.png)I am using the selectpicker library to my `@Html.DropDownListFor`, my input field is as I added in the picture, although there is no error in the console.I'm not using select on the first input in the image, but using it on the second input.I can't click and it won't open.
Important : If I use the
`<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` library, I don't get an error. But some features on my page are lost so I shouldn't use it.

DROPDOWNLIST :

```
 <div class="mb-3">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Repairs.urunAd, "Ürün", new { @class = "form-label" })
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Repairs.urunID, Model.ProductsList, "Lütfen Bir Ürün Seçiniz*", new { @class = "form-control repair-inputs selectpicker", id = "repairProductInput", required = "required", data_live_search = "true" })
 </div>
```

LIBS :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.1/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.22.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.22.1/dist/bootstrap-table-locale-all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/repair.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#repairProductInput').selectpicker();
    });
</script>
```